# Show that two segments are the same measure.

Tags: geometry, proof-writing, solution-verification, triangles, alternative-proof

On side $AB$ and $AC$ on the outside of any triangle $ABC$ there are built equilateral triangles $ABD$ and $ACE$. Let $F$ be point such that $\sphericalangle CBF=\sphericalangle FCB=30° $. Prove that $|DF|=|FE|$.
[image]

---
Notice that triangles $DAC$ and $BAE$ are congruent, so $|DC|=|BE|$ and $\sphericalangle AEB=\sphericalangle ACD$. From this we have: $$\sphericalangle BGC=180°-\sphericalangle EGC=180°-(180°-(60°-\sphericalangle AEB)-(60°+\sphericalangle ACD))=120°$$
So, $$\sphericalangle EBF + 30°+(30°-\sphericalangle FCD)=180°-120°=60° \Rightarrow \sphericalangle EBF=\sphericalangle FCD$$
Since $|FB|=|FC|$,  triangles $DFC$ and $BEF$ are congruent so $|DF|=|EF|$.

---

This proof seems fine, but it only works when point $F$ is inside triangle $ABC$. Are there any other more universal ways to prove this statement using congruency of triangles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: F outside triangle ABC]
**I.** The proof by congruent triangles also works if $G$ is within but $F$ is outside triangle $ABC$.

We still have $\angle BGC=120^o$. And since, as OP calculates$$\angle EBF+30^o+(30^o-\angle FCD)=\angle EGC=180^o-120^o=60^o$$then$$\angle EBF+60^o-\angle FCD=60^o$$making$$\angle EBF-\angle FCD=0$$and therefore$$\angle EBF=\angle FCD$$and$$DF=FE$$

**II.** Further, if $F$ is within triangle $ABC$ but $G$ is outside, as in the next figure
[image: G outside triangle]
we have$$\angle EBC=\angle EGC+\angle BCG$$i.e.$$\angle EBF+30^o=60^o+\angle FCD-30^o$$or$$\angle EBF+60^o=60^o+\angle FCD$$so that again$$\angle EBF=\angle FCD$$and$$DF=FE$$

**III.** Lastly, even if $F$ and $G$ are both outside triangle $ABC$
[image: F and G both outside triangle ABC]
again we get$$\angle EBC=\angle EGC+\angle BCG$$i.e.$$\angle EBF+30^o=60^o+\angle FCD-30^o$$or$$\angle EBF+60^o=60^o+\angle FCD$$so that again$$\angle EBF=\angle FCD$$and$$DF=FE$$

Hence it seems the proof by congruent triangles that $DF=FE$ applies generally.

Comment: In the first case, how did you calculate that angle EBF is equal to angle FCD

Comment: By your method: $\angle EBF+30^o+(30^o-\angle FCD)=180^o-120^o=60^o$.  So   $\angle EBF+60^o-\angle FCD=60^o$, i.e. $\angle EBF-\angle FCD=0$, making $\angle EBF=\angle FCD$.